# Problem with the Gradle files. I have already connected the project to Firebase and now I am trying to add Google map

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, android-studio, build.gradle

My project is connected to Firebase (Database) and now I am tring to add Google map. When I add one of the dependencies I get an error message while the sync.
It says something about using different version etc.

HELP !!

Description:

After I added this line to the app gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

I got this error:

```
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

with out the line that I have added everything is fine.

app gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rotem.bepart_appproject"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

**implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'**

}
```

my project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
**implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'**
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

Keeping the same version for all Firebase dependencies is now anti-pattern.

Comment: What to do if it works now but- when I ran the app I see only the google logo and there is no map ??

Comment: Regarding the second issue, I think is not a dependency related issue. But for that, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I found one on other post. To change to:implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'

Comment: But thank you for helping !! and I can't post another question... I have to wait for some reason for 90 minutes... :( If someone can help me here...

Comment: Why do you say that my solution didn't work? Isn't the error gone? `15.0.0` are a little older.

Comment: Do you have the same error? As I understood, your app compiles fine, right?